# Need to update table cell one by one during ajax call when the table is iterated in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

//Sample code:
I need to update the status in a column of every row one by one in html table when i get response from the ajax call,but the status cell gets updated when all the ajax request is complete.I don't want all the cells getting updated at once.

```
<script>
 for(var i=0;i< count;i++)
{

 $.ajax({
      url: 'example.php',
      type: 'POST',
      async : false,
      data: {test:test},
     success: function (data) { 
             $("#"+i).html("updated");
           }
   });
}
</script>
 <html>
    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Address</th>
           <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr><td>Xavier</td><td>London</td><td><span id=0>Pending</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jhon</td><td>NY</td><td><span id=1>Pending</span></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Sam</td><td>LA</td><td><span id=2>Pending</span></td></tr>
       </tbody>




  </table>
</html>
```

The output should be:

```
Name      Address       Status

Xavier    London        Updated

John      NY            Pending

Sam       LA           Pending
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? By the way, it looks like you are making an AJAX call for every cell/row. It's a bad idea from the performance point of view. In your situation I would make a single AJAX call to get all statuses and then update the table.

Comment: The status cell which i need to update when i get response from the ajax.But the status cell of all the row are getting updated when the loop ends.(i want to update 'status' cell of each row 1 by 1).

Comment: I'm still can't figure out what you are trying to achieve or what the problem is.

Comment: The table is getting updated only when the response for all the three row are received but i want to update the row only when i get the response for that row.

Comment: instead of making n number of ajax calls in the loop, just send whole data at once to the server and loop over their. it will improve your page performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to update the entire row at once then call the ajax function for each rows. When you return a row from your "example.php" display it and then call ajax again and return next row.

Comment: I don't want to update an entire row only that particular status cell.
can you give any sample code for that.Thanks for the help!!